# How do i select a texbox and search a content and chose first option in selenium - python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hey I have this site : https://realmeupdater.com/
I want to search my query and get the first result url by clicking it. how can i do this? I tried to click element and send query but it gives me some error.

Here is The Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import asyncio
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN = 'path'
CHROME_DRIVER = 'path'

async def realme_rom_search(query):
    url = "https://realmeupdater.com/"
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.binary_location = GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER, options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    select_ccs = "select2-device-container"
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, select_ccs))).click()
    elem = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > span > span > span.select2-search.select2-search--dropdown > input")))
    elem.send_keys(query)
    elem.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
    elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

But i Get This Error:

```
File "<string>", line 30, in realme_rom_search
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-device-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true">...</span> is not clickable at point (457, 586). Other element would receive the click: <div role="dialog" aria-live="polite" aria-label="cookieconsent" aria-describedby="cookieconsent:desc" class="cc-window cc-banner cc-type-opt-out cc-theme-classic cc-bottom cc-color-override--1142219405 " style="">...</div>
  (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

All I want to do is search and go to the url and get rom info and url, can anyone help me?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to scroll till the end of the web page to let selenium know where is the drop down.

Use the below code to scroll till end :

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
```

Secondly this drop is built using UI and LI elements so Select class from Selenium will not work. All you need to do is to store all elements in a list and then you can look for element which is desired and after string comparison you can click on it. Below is the sample code  :

**Code  :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users:\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://realmeupdater.com/")
sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "select2-device-container"))).click()
all_options = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#select2-device-results li")
for option in all_options:
    if option.text =='realme 2 Pro (RMX1801EX)':
        option.click()
print("Operation done successfully")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. The locator you are using is not unique. This is not causing problems in this specific case, but generally it would be better to use unique locator.
2. The element you trying to click is initially out of the visible screen, so you first need to scroll it into the view.
3. There is a elements block asking to accept cookies on the bottom. That element is currently actually accepting your click. However I guess this could be resolved by scrolling your element into view.
   So, please try the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selectorid(select_ccs)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

This should help.
If it still not enough, try closing the cookies block before that so it will be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[aria-label="deny cookies"]'))).click()

wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[aria-label="dismiss cookie message"]'))).click()

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selectorid(select_ccs)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```